# Javascript Button not working

Tags: javascript, button

In this piece of code my button isn't working:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id='txt'>
    Unicorns
</p>
<button onclick="buttonChange()">Press</button>
<script>
function buttonChange() {
    var button=confirm("Press Me");
    if (button==true) {
        fn()
    }
}
var color = '#33cc33',
    elem  = document.getElementById('txt');

function fn() {
    elem.style.color = color;
    setTimeout(function() {
        color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        fn();
    }, 500);
}();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well that's not entirely true. To get the button to work I change the function fn() to a IIFE function.

Not much, but it works. Problem is the button works the fn() doesn't work. When the fn() works the button doesn't. My main goal is to have the button ask whether you want the word "Unicorn" to randomly switch colors.

Summary: If you press ok, the fn() function begins (therefore making unicorn appear and change colours), when you press cancel, simply nothing happens.

Comment: Your paragraph should be inside the <body> (before your script also), not outside the body btw.

Comment: You have a syntax error with `function fn() { ... }()` That's not valid. Please open your developer console to look for syntax errors.

Comment: In the future, creating an example on JSFiddle can help us answerers immensely.

Comment: Even better than creating a JSFiddle is properly indenting your code.

Comment: @cookiemonster Ya I know, I didn't really get how to add code in so I just guessed

Comment: @phylax and others that approved the code changes, don't do changes that rewrite the code to meet your coding style. Formatting/indentation changes are fine, but leave the rest original.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, the function should be declared as:

```
function fn() {
    elem.style.color = color;
    setTimeout(function() {
        color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        fn();
    }, 500);
};
```

(Note the removal of the parentheses at the end)

This function will continue to update the color of `Unicorn` every half second until the page is refreshed.  If you only want it to be updated once:

```
function fn() {
    elem.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one possible approach:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="buttonChange()">Press</button>
    <p id='txt'>Unicorns</p>    
    <script>
        function buttonChange() {
            var button = confirm("Press Me");
            if (button) {
                fn();
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(unicornsTimeout);
            }
        }
        var color = '#33cc33',
            elem = document.getElementById('txt'),
            unicornsTimeout = 0;

        function fn() {
            elem.style.color = color;
            unicornsTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                fn();
            }, 500);
        }
        fn();
    </script>
</body>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8C65/). Apart from fixing obvious syntax errors, all the elements are now contained within `<body>`, `<script>` goes last, so all the code will be executed when DOM is already in place.

To implement cancellation of random unicorns, I've introduced another variable that stores the timeout ID - that allows to clear that timeout in `buttonChange`.

---

I'd say the most interesting part of this question is the difference between `function fn(){}()` and `(function fn() {})()` statements in context of accessibility of `fn` within `buttonChange`. The point is, wrapping `function fn()` in parenthesis turns this statement from `Function Declaration` to `Function Expression`, meaning that `fn` name becomes only meaningful within the function itself, and doesn't interfere with the rest of the scope.

Comment: I think OP wanted to auto-start the color changes. So one call of `fn()` missing?

Comment: @phylax Misunderstood the OP's intent originally, added the code for that. )

Answer (score 0):

By making `fn()` an immediate function you make it inaccessible for your other code. Remove the parentheses around fn.

To start the timeout just call `fn()` once after defining it.

And then it can be called from within `buttonChange()`

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure the var color is undefined in your function, since you set it outside the function. Either pass your var color with the function, or set it IN the function. Try to use your browsers console, to read any JS errors created (F12 in most).

and I mean this part:

```
elem.style.color = color;
```

And extra;

```
();
```

remove that above that /script tag.

Comment: I think you need to read it again; `fn()` is called within the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: It runs first via buttonChange

Comment: Your line `elem.style.color` being wrong doesn't have anything to do with what is starting it; it's setting it once the `setTimeout()` callback is run again.

Comment: Ye, and the very first run, called from buttonChange the var color is undefined. Then the function fn is called again, and just only then its being set.

Comment: `var color = '#33cc33'` Since that is in the global scope (not in a function), that's the same as `window.color` or `color` is set when it is first run, and set again once it is run again. It's not undefined on first run, or after.

Comment: Why do you think it's undefined? It looks very clearly defined to me.

Comment: eh nvm. You are right.

Comment: It is set: http://jsfiddle.net/JpbaR/